# VMWare failing to boot Ubuntu guest after upgrade of host from Windows 8.0 to 8.1

Tags: windows-8, vmware, ubuntu-13.04

I upgraded from Windows 8.0 to 8.1 today, which seems to have gone fine. I jokingly suggested that it might bugger up my virtual machine and it seems to have done so.

When trying to power on my Ubuntu 13 guest in VMWare Player 6.0.1 I received the error:

```
"Error while powering on: Internal error."
```

Does anyone have any advice? I'm willing and able to provide more useful information, if you can tell me what's needed.

Comment: I would first try and install VMWare Player.  Make sure you install the current version of VMWare Player.

Comment: I concur with @Ramhound, try Uninstalling and then reinstalling VMWare Player.  You also may want to check/consider a couple things: 1) Is this error just with this one VM, or is it ALL VM's?  2) Was 6.0.1 the version to last used with it before upgrading Windows?  If you move the VM to another computer, does it work there?

Comment: I would like to add that in my personal experience. Even if the virtual machine booted the network adapter wouldn't have worked. I had to install VMWare Workstation 10 after I upgraded my own machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vmware installs drivers for 64bit Intel-VT and AMD-VT? Technologies, networking and some other stuff. It seems like these drivers goes away while upgrading your OS. Remove Vmware and reinstall it, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Aye, reinstalling did fix it. I don't know whether or not it removed the extra drivers, but a reinstall of exactly the same version of VMWare did fix it. Thanks to all who offered advice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue (player 6.0.1 - 1379776 on Win 8.1 after upgrade from Player 5, all VMs stopped working with "Error while powering on: Internal error.", VMs worked fine on another Win 8.1 machine) by repairing the install (re-ran the original 6.0.1 installer, chose Repair).

Comment: Confirmed... the repair option of the installer worked fine for me, too. No re-installation needed. I simply downloaded the latest installer from vmware.